# Como hacer un metodo para reducir javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones

Ustedes saben como hago para reducir este `javascript` con algún método?

Tengo que capturar los **id** de algunos `input` pero no se como hacer un método que me lo permita y reducir a un solo `if` y `else` mi código, mi inconveniente es que debo reemplazar los valores con los datos correspondientes.

```
$('#rut-input-company, #rut-input-company-debtor').on('change', function(event){
        var rut_company = $(this).val();
        var expression = new RegExp(rut_company, "i");
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/companies',
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data){
                const company = data.find(c => c.rut.search(expression) > -1);
                if (company) {
                    $('.form-group-company').removeClass('hide');
                    if (company.name !== null ){
                        $('#name-input-company, .name-input-company').addClass('disabled-input');
                        $('#name-input-company, .name-input-company').val(company.name);
                    } else {
                        $('#name-input-company, .name-input-company').empty();
                        $('#name-input-company, .name-input-company').removeClass('disabled-input');
                    };
                    if (company.address !== null ){
                        $('#address-input-company').addClass('disabled-input');
                        $('#address-input-company').val(company.address);
                    } else {
                        $('#address-input-company').val('');
                        $('#address-input-company').removeClass('disabled-input');
                    };
                    if (company.phone_number !== null ){
                        $('#phone_number-input-company').addClass('disabled-input');
                        $('#phone_number-input-company').val(company.phone_number);
                    } else {
                        $('#phone_number-input-company').val('');
                        $('#phone_number-input-company').removeClass('disabled-input');
                    };
                    if (company.email !== null ){
                        $('#email-input-company').addClass('disabled-input');
                        $('#email-input-company').val(company.email);
                    } else {
                        $('#email-input-company').val('');
                        $('#email-input-company').removeClass('disabled-input');
                    };
                    
                } else {
                    $('#name-input-company').val('');
                    $('.form-group-company').removeClass('hide');
                    $('.form-control-company').removeClass('disabled-input');
                }
            },
        });
    });
```

Este es mi gran código.

Hay algunos selectores con **clases** pero lo puedo cambiar a **id** si es necesario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes re factorizar tu código de la siguiente manera.

```js
const validateCompanyProperty = function (company, property) {
  if (company[property] !== null) {
    $(`#${property}-input-company, .${property}-input-company`).addClass(
      "disabled-input"
    );
    $(`#${property}-input-company, .${property}-input-company`).val(
      company[property]
    );
  } else {
    $(`#${property}-input-company, .${property}-input-company`).empty();
    $(`#${property}-input-company, .${property}-input-company`).removeClass(
      "disabled-input"
    );
  }
};

const validateCompany = function (company) {
  if (company) {
    $(".form-group-company").removeClass("hide");
    Object.keys(company).forEach((property)=>{
      validateCompanyProperty(company, property);
    });
  } else {
    $("#name-input-company").val("");
    $(".form-group-company").removeClass("hide");
    $(".form-control-company").removeClass("disabled-input");
  }
};

$("#rut-input-company, #rut-input-company-debtor").on(
  "change",
  function (event) {
    var rut_company = $(this).val();
    var expression = new RegExp(rut_company, "i");
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/companies",
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function (data) {
        const company = data.find((c) => c.rut.search(expression) > -1);
        validateCompany(company);
      },
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirve! y aprendí cosas nuevas, saludos